# Formatting text in html based on scope array

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a scope array

```
$scope.myArr = [{'id':'1','vehicle':'car'},{'id':'1','vehicle':'bike'}]
```

I need to show this data in my html page as below

```
 |id|vehicle|
 |--|-------|
 |1 |car    |
 |2 |bike   |
```

Is there any way I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat like this,

```
<tr>
    <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in myArr[0]">{{ key }}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in myArr">
    <td ng-repeat="column in row">
      {{ column }}
    </td>
</tr>
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myArr = [{'id':'1','vehicle':'car'},{'id':'1','vehicle':'bike'}]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<table ng-controller="myController" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in myArr[0]">{{ key }}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in myArr">
    <td ng-repeat="column in row">
      {{ column }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to obtain it as a table. But I need it in a formatted way as mentioned.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: I might be able to do this using <pre> tags if the data is static, but $scope.myArr is dynamic so I cannot give  a fixed space between data etc

Comment: thats something related to css